# Can properties be accessed as types?

Tags: c#, .net, properties, lambda, functional-programming

Can I access object properties as a type?

I am using an API where I have to iterate through a collection of objects, and access the `Text` properties of two of these objects, either for reading or for writing. I currently have two methods for reading and writing as follows:

```
Result ReadTexts()
    var attribs = SOME_CODE;
    string first = "", second = "";

    for(int i=1 ; i <= attribs.Count ; i++) {
        if(attribs[i] IS_FIRST_ONE_NEEDED) {
            first = attribs[i].Text;
        } else if(attribs[i] IS_SECOND_ONE_NEEDED) {
            second = attribs[i].Text;
        }
    }
    return new Result(first, second);
}

void WriteTexts(string first, string second) {
    var attribs = SOME_CODE;

    for(int i=1 ; i <= attribs.Count ; i++) {
        if(attribs[i] IS_FIRST_ONE_NEEDED) {
            attribs[i].Text = first;
        } else if(attribs[i] IS_SECOND_ONE_NEEDED) {
            attribs[i].Text = second;
        }
    }
}
```

What I would prefer is using a more functional style which factors out the iteration and checking for the two objects in the collection into one method instead of repeating this code, as actually SOME_CODE as well as IS_FIRST_ONE_NEEDED and IS_SECOND_ONE_NEEDED are a bit longer in reality than in the above sample code. This one method would look like:

```
void AccessTexts(Action<StringProperty> first, Action<StringProperty> second) {
    var attribs = SOME_CODE;

    for(int i=1 ; i <= attribs.Count ; i++) {
        if(attribs[i] IS_FIRST_ONE_NEEDED) {
            first(attribs[i].Text);
        } else if(attribs[i] IS_SECOND_ONE_NEEDED) {
            second(attribs[i].Text);
        }
    }
}
```

and then call this with lambda expressions like

```
AccessTexts(( prop => prop = "abc"), ( prop => prop = "def"));
```

for writing, or

```
AccessTexts(( prop => firstString = prop), ( prop => secondString = prop));
```

for reading. This would be much shorter and avoid repeating a lot of code.

But I think this is not possible, as properties are not exposed as a real type in .net, but are just based on the availability of special methods - the getter and setter. Hence, there is no type `StringProperty` as I used it as type of the delegate parameter in the code sample of "what I would like to write".

Am I right, or is there some way to implement it the way I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your own class that represents a property.  As you've shown, a property is essentially just a get and set method, so that's all our class needs to represent.

As for how to create such a thing, one option is to have the type accept a getter and setter as delegates directly.  Another option is to have it accept a `PropertyInfo` and an object which can then use reflection to implement the getter and setter methods.  Finally, if you wanted to, you could even use an `Expression` to represent the property access, and then pull out the PropertyInfo from that.

So to start out with, the actual wrapper itself:

```
public class PropertyWrapper<T>
{
    private Func<T> getter;
    private Action<T> setter;

    public PropertyWrapper(PropertyInfo property, object instance)
    {
        if (!typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(property.PropertyType))
            throw new ArgumentException("Property type doesn't match type supplied");

        setter = value => property.SetValue(instance, value);
        getter = () => (T)property.GetValue(instance);
    }

    public PropertyWrapper(Func<T> getter, Action<T> setter)
    {
        this.setter = setter;
        this.getter = getter;
    }

    public T Get()
    {
        return getter();
    }

    public void Set(T value)
    {
        setter(value);
    }

    public T Value
    {
        get { return getter(); }
        set { setter(value); }
    }
}
```

You can then use a helper such as this (it's extracted out of the other class so that there is generic type inference:

```
public class PropertyWrapper
{
    public static PropertyWrapper<TProp> Create<TObject, TProp>(
        TObject instance, Expression<Func<TObject, TProp>> expression)
    {
        var memberEx = expression.Body as MemberExpression;
        var prop = memberEx.Member as PropertyInfo;

        return new PropertyWrapper<TProp>(prop, instance);
    }
}
```

Here is a simple example of constructing such an object using the two different syntaxes:

```
var list = new List<int>();

var prop1 = new PropertyWrapper<int>(
    () => list.Capacity, cap => list.Capacity = cap);

var prop2 = PropertyWrapper.Create(list, l => l.Capacity);

prop2.Value = 42;
Console.WriteLine(list.Capacity); //prints 42
```

Comment: So there is no "Property" type in .net, but your solution creates a .net type using reflection and the `PropertyInfo` reflection type available in .net. If using pre-.net 4.5, `SetValue()` and `GetValue` need an additional `null` last argument.

Comment: @FrankPl The solution doesn't *require* reflection, it simply has two optional creation methods that use reflection in order to have a more terse creation syntax.  If you want to write out the getter/setter explicitly it's a non-reflection solution.

Answer (score 0):

What you did is definitely workable. You are providing an accessor for the property in question to your function `AccessTexts` so that the function does not care how the access is done.

Normally, this would be solved using an interface implemented by the object being iterated over, or implemented by a wrapper class.

You can also use reflection or `dynamic` to do the access.

In any case you need a proxy between `AccessTexts` and the real objects.

Comment: You mean I would define a class, say `Proxy`, which has a constructor to encapsulate one of the collection objects, and a property, say `Text` which delegates both the getter and setter to the original object. Then I would use that type as parameter type of the actions?

Then it would be easier to just use the collection objects themselves as the parameter of the actions/delegates. This would not solve my requirement to just expose the property, but would solve the main issue to avoid code repetition.